# Find the probability of observing more than $2$ arrivals in $10$ seconds

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

Arrivals at a service facility occur at random (Poisson distributed) at a mean rate of $10$ per minute. Find the probability of observing more than $2$ arrivals in $10$ seconds.
I've begun to answer this question using the poisson tables:

$P(\gt2$ arrivals in an interval of $10$ seconds)

$=1-P(\le2$ arrivals in $60$ seconds) $=0.9972$

I have then gone onto divide this answer by $6$ giving me the answer of $0.1662$

Really not sure if this is correct.

Comment: You may be dividing by $6$ at the wrong point.  If the rate is $10$ per minute, what is the rate per $10$ seconds? Then find $1 - P(\text{arrivals} \le 2 \text{ in } 10 \text{ seconds})$

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Henry , the rate per $10$ seconds is then $\frac{5}{3}$ using this with the Poisson table I now have the answer $0.7834$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the mean of $10$ arrivals per minute implies the mean of $\frac{5}{3}$ arrivals per $10$ seconds. So:
$$P(X>2)=1-P(X\le 2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)=\\
1-\frac{e^{-\frac 53}\cdot \left(\frac 53\right)^0}{0!}-\frac{e^{-\frac 53}\cdot \left(\frac 53\right)^1}{1!}-\frac{e^{-\frac 53}\cdot \left(\frac 53\right)^2}{2!}=1-e^{-\frac 53}\left(1+\frac 53+\frac{25}{18}\right)=0.234.$$ 
Intuitively, if the mean arrival is $\frac 53$ per $10$ seconds, the probability of more than $2$ arrivals in $10$ seconds will be less than $0.5$.